# Worklight v6 - How to set headers for proxy basic authentication

Tags: authentication, proxy, ibm-mobilefirst

i've set up a worklight server behind a proxy. 
The proxy makes the basic authentication and handles the ssl certificate (signed by VeriSign).

How to configure my worklight client app to pass the credentials in the header for basic authentication on my proxy?
Is there anything to deal with the https certificate on client side?
I can't find any information in the IBM Infocenter...

For information, my apps and server work fine without proxy and ssl.
Thanx.

Answer (score 0):

So this proxy is an SSL terminator and a basic authenticator. 
Basically , if the proxy will forward the Authorization HTTP header in the request and the WWW-Authenticate header in the response it should be ok.
can you attach wireshark dump from the Worklight server to show what headers were sent to/from Worklight server ?